# Stripe error: The users credit card failed

Tags: javascript, php, stripe-payments

I'm using Stripe to handle payments on my website. But, when I try to make a payment I'm getting a 'The users credit card failed' error. I've used this code on different sites and they work but, for some reason it isn't working here. Does anyone know what the problem might be? There definitely is money on the card:

```
function stripeResponseHandler(status, response)
{
if (response.error) 
{
  // Stripe.js failed to generate a token. The error message will explain why.
  // Usually, it's because the customer mistyped their card info.
  // You should customize this to present the message in a pretty manner:
  alert(response.error.message);
} 
else
{  
  // Stripe.js generated a token successfully. We're ready to charge the card!
  var token = response.id;
  var email = $("#email").val();
   var price = $("#price").val();
   var id = $("id").val();

  // Make the call to the server-script to process the order.
  // Pass the token and non-sensitive form information.
  var request = $.ajax ({
     type: "POST",
     url: "pay.php",
     dataType: "json",
     data: {
        "stripeToken" : token,
        "email" : email,
        "price" : price,
        "id" : id 
        }
  });

  request.done(function(msg)
  {
     if (msg.result === 0)
     {
        // Customize this section to present a success message and display whatever
        // should be displayed to the user.
         window.location.replace("http://foo.com");

     }
     else
     {
        // The card was NOT charged successfully, but we interfaced with Stripe
        // just fine. There's likely an issue with the user's credit card.
        // Customize this section to present an error explanation
        alert("The user's credit card failed.");
     }
  });

  request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus)
  {
     // We failed to make the AJAX call to pay.php. Something's wrong on our end.
     // This should not normally happen, but we need to handle it if it does.
     alert("error");
  });
  }
 }

  function showErrorDialogWithMessage(message)
  {
  // For the tutorial, we'll just do an alert. You should customize this function to 
 // present "pretty" error messages on your page.
 alert(message);
// Re-enable the order button so the user can try again
$('#buy-submit-button').removeAttr("disabled");
}

$(document).ready(function() 
{
$('#buy-form').submit(function(event)
{
  // immediately disable the submit button to prevent double submits
  $('#buy-submit-button').attr("disabled", "disabled");

  var fName = $('#first-name').val();
  var lName = $('#last-name').val();
  var email = $('#email').val();
  var cardNumber = $('#card-number').val();
  var cardCVC = $('#card-security-code').val();

  // First and last name fields: make sure they're not blank
  if (fName === "") {
     showErrorDialogWithMessage("Please enter your first name.");
     return;
  }
  if (lName === "") {
     showErrorDialogWithMessage("Please enter your last name.");
     return;
  }

  // Validate the email address:
  var emailFilter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
  if (email === "") {
     showErrorDialogWithMessage("Please enter your email address.");
     return;
  } else if (!emailFilter.test(email)) {
     showErrorDialogWithMessage("Your email address is not valid.");
     return;
  }

  // Stripe will validate the card number and CVC for us, so just make sure they're not         blank
  if (cardNumber === "") {
     showErrorDialogWithMessage("Please enter your card number.");
     return;
  }
  if (cardCVC === "") {
     showErrorDialogWithMessage("Please enter your card security code.");
     return;
  }


Stripe.createToken({
number: cardNumber,
cvc: cardCVC,
exp_month: $('#expiration-month').val(),
exp_year: $('#expiration-year').val()
 }, stripeResponseHandler);

 // Prevent the default submit action on the form
 return false;
 });
 });
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Because they're skint??

Comment: In the `request.done` closure you have an unclosed string. Use a text editor with syntax highlighting. Also, use your browser's error console.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen This wasn't the problem. I've edited it now but, that error only appeared because I changed the url to foo.com for privacy sake, in my application the string is closed

Comment: @dwhite.me This is not the case as I am using my own card and I am 100% certain there is money on there

Comment: Balance isn't always the only reason why a credit card transaction gets declined. I would try another credit card first

Comment: @Pekka웃 Tried 3 different cards already and getting the same error

Comment: It was not a serious comment